# Replace text by html. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace text by html tags. I'm using this code:

```
  $('p').each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(http:\/\/.+?)(\s|$)/g, function(text, link) {
               return '<a href="'+ link +'" target="blank">'+ link +'</a>';
            }).replace(/(www\..+?)(\s|$)/g, function(text, link) {
               return '<a href="http://'+ link +'" target="blank">'+ link +'</a>';
                })
            );  
        });
```

But the problem is that it's not replacing the text by html, but by another text.

For example:

```
          www.google.com
```

becomes (still in text):

```
          <a href="http://www.google.fr" target="blank">www.google.fr</a>
```

Any idea on how I could solve that?

Comment: You've created an XSS hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).text(...)
```

You're setting the **text** of the element.

To set HTML, call `.html()`.

Answer (score 1):

use `.html()` :

```
 $('p').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(http:\/\/.+?)(\s|$)/g, function(text, link) {
               return '<a href="'+ link +'" target="blank">'+ link +'</a>';
            }).replace(/(www\..+?)(\s|$)/g, function(text, link) {
               return '<a href="http://'+ link +'" target="blank">'+ link +'</a>';
                })
            );  
        });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sjy6g/)